# Zabbix - timeleft and forecast triggers not working

Tags: triggers, prediction, zabbix

I'm having problems to configure the new Zabbix predictive triggers that were added in version 3.0 and later.

I'm running a Zabbix 3.2 server and configuring the predictive triggers as follows:

```
{hostname:vfs.fs.size[/,free].timeleft(7d,,102745398)}<1h
{hostname:vfs.fs.size[/,free].forecast(7d,,1h)}<102745398
```

From what I understood of the confusing documentation of these triggers (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/triggers/prediction), they're supposed to work like this:

The "timeleft" trigger should use the last 7 days of historic data to predict the free space and warn me 1h before the threshold is gonna be reached (102745398Kb in this case, which corresponds to 10% of free space).

I don't think I understand the "forecast" trigger at all, but I configured it anyway to see how it behaves.

Initially I had configured both triggers with "pfree" instead of "free", like this:

```
{hostname:vfs.fs.size[/,pfree].timeleft(7d,,10)}<1h
{hostname:vfs.fs.size[/,pfree].forecast(7d,,1h)}<10
```

It didn't work as well.

Am I doing something wrong in the triggers, or do they need a specific configuration done previously for them to work? All I did was to configure the triggers for the Item in Zabbix and nothing else. Also, I'm not very confident on my understanding of them, could someone explain them to me a little bit better?

Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to be sure without seeing your data - these functions operate based on the rate of change. How did you conclude that there's less than 1 hour left ?

Comment: Because the host I'm using for testing punctually goes below 10% space every night at 03:00AM due to a routine that takes some disk space and frees it after it is run. Here's a 7d graph of it: [http://puu.sh/rAlqj/96614a2719.png](http://puu.sh/rAlqj/96614a2719.png)

As you can see, this is the perfect scenario for testing since disk usage on this machine is very predictable.

Comment: Ah - then you might want to set the period not to 7 days but 30 minutes. Looking at the data for 7 days, one would likely conclude that it will take a long time for the disk to be full. Looking at the last 30 minutes with the free space constantly dropping, the picture would look completely different.

Comment: Thank you, I set the period to a shorter time and it worked as I expected!

Comment: Great, added that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to set the period not to 7 days but 30 minutes. Looking at the data for 7 days, one would likely conclude that it will take a long time for the disk to be full. Looking at the last 30 minutes with the free space constantly dropping, the picture would look completely different.